# Mixed blend mode difference doesn't work with transform rotate

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a hover effect, where the span moves over the text, inverting the text color along the way. I also want the text to be rotated (just rotated, not rotating animation).
I am using react and tailwind css.

this works:

```
<button
  className={` relative px-1 py-[2px] text-sm font-medium text-black group `}
>
  <span className="border-[0px] border-red-500 absolute inset-0  bg-white mix-blend-difference w-[0%] group-hover:w-[100%] transition-[width]" />
  test
</button>
```

but this doesn't work:

```
<button
  className={` relative px-1 py-[2px] text-sm font-medium text-black group rotate-12`}
>
  <span className="border-[0px] border-red-500 absolute inset-0  bg-white mix-blend-difference w-[0%] group-hover:w-[100%] transition-[width]" />
  test
</button>
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: It happens because as per [the CSS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode), the element is "blended and composited with the stacking context that contains the element." Adding a `transform` element will cause that element to create a new stacking context, causing the inner `mix-blend-difference` to only blend with elements within the `rotate-12` parent.